# how to parse the following json string in php

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to parse following json in php and get all the values

```
{"Student":
 [
 {  "adm_no":"101/1", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
 {  "adm_no":"101/6", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0 },
 {  "adm_no":"12/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
 {  "adm_no":"14/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
 { "adm_no":"147/1", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0 },
 {  "adm_no":"45/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0}
  ],
 "class":"s3b",
"username":"4"
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far. btw you might try looking at json_encode / json_decode functions

Comment: Can you more clear on what you want to do? You could use json_decode() function and then access the values

Comment: my question is after json_decode() how to parse the values of student, class and user name

Comment: After `json_decode` you don't need to "parse" anything, it's just PHP arrays and objects that you access normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = '{"Student":
   [
   {  "adm_no":"101/1", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
   {  "adm_no":"101/6", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0 },
   {  "adm_no":"12/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
   {  "adm_no":"14/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
   { "adm_no":"147/1", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0 },
   {  "adm_no":"45/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0}
    ],
   "class":"s3b",
  "username":"4"
  }';
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach($array->Student as $std){
 echo "Adm_no: ".$std->adm_no."<br>";
}
```

Comment: its working and i get the values of adm_no but how to get the values class and username

Comment: echo $array->class; echo $array->username;

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{"Student":
   [
   {  "adm_no":"101/1", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
   {  "adm_no":"101/6", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0 },
   {  "adm_no":"12/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
   {  "adm_no":"14/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0},
   { "adm_no":"147/1", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0 },
   {  "adm_no":"45/12", "teacher_id":"4", "attendance":0}
    ],
   "class":"s3b",
  "username":"4"
  }';
$out = json_decode($json);
foreach($out->Student as $adm){
echo "Adm_no: ".$adm->adm_no."<br/>";
}
echo "Class : ".$out->class."<br/>";
echo "Username : ".$out->username."<br/>";
```